# Overlay points on top of violin plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to overlay the true values of a simulation on the violin plots for the simulated values. Preferably tiny horizontal lines, but points are ok. This is as far as I got, since the true values have different names (b1,b3) as the simulation values (mrdoc2_b1_hat ...) I cannot overlay one on top the other, how to go about it?

```r
# Create a new data frame for plotting
plot_data <- bias %>%
  select(mrdoc2_b1_hat, b1,
         mrdoc2_b3_hat, b3) %>%
  select(!contains("_se")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
               names_to = "key", values_to = "value") 

# Create the plot
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = reorder(key, -value), y = value)) +
  geom_violin(data = plot_data %>% filter(str_detect(key, "_hat$")), trim = TRUE, scale = "width") +
  geom_boxplot(data = plot_data %>% filter(str_detect(key, "_hat$")), width = 0.19, fill = "white") +
  geom_point(data = plot_data %>% filter(!str_detect(key, "_hat$")),
             aes(x = key, y = mean(value), group = key), color = "red", size = 3) +  # Overlay point for mean of b1
  theme_luis() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reshape your data so that it has one column for the x axis variable (b1/b3) and two value columns - one for the simulated data and one for actual data. This prevents all the tedious filtering of data in each layer.

```r
library(tidyverse)

bias %>%
  rename_with(~paste("actual", .x, sep = "_"), matches("b\\d")) %>%
  rename_with(~gsub("^.*_(.*)_.*$", "simulated_\\1", .x), contains("mrdoc")) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_sep = "_", 
               names_to = c(".value", "group")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = simulated)) +
  geom_violin(trim = TRUE, scale = "width") +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.19, fill = "white") +
  geom_point(color = "red", size = 3, 
             aes(y = mean(actual), shape = "Mean of real data")) +  
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(123)

bias <- replicate(4, 1.9^(rnorm(200, 5))/40 - 0.5) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(c("b1", "b3", "mrdoc2_b1_hat", "mrdoc2_b3_hat"))
```

The above data creates the following plot with the OP's original code:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Allan, this solves the issue. Could  you please also have a look at the alternative version with ggdisc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78093255/is-it-possible-to-alternate-geoms-in-ggplot2?noredirect=1#comment137674342_78093255