# Is it possible to alternate geoms in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggdist

I want the geom point to alternate between the halfeye densities. The objective is to have true values close to the simulated density curve, so b3_hat then b3 right below. Is it possible? Here is the code:

```
library(forcats)
library(ggdist)

# use the bias data to plot the halfeye
plot_data <-bias %>%
  select(mrdoc2_b1_hat, b1,
         mrdoc2_b3_hat, b3) %>%
  select(!contains("_se")) %>%
  # pivot all columns
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_to = "key", values_to = "value")


# Create the halfeye plot
 
plot_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = fct_reorder(key, value))) +
  stat_halfeye(data = plot_data %>% filter(str_detect(key, "_hat$"))) +
  # we'll add the data back in too (scale = .5 above adjusts the halfeye height so
  # that the data fit in as well)
  geom_point(aes(x = value), data = plot_data %>% filter(!str_detect(key, "_hat$")), pch = "|", size = 2, position = position_nudge(y = -.15))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share a sufficient sample of `bias`? Or perhaps switch to public dataset. My first thought (lacking a working example) is to change the order of the factors; I know you're using `fct_reorder`, but without seeing the data it's hard to know for certain.

Comment: Another option would be to use the same names for the y variables in both datasets (maybe "b1" and "b3") since you're already using position_nudge to offset them.